# Does NBOpenGL really worth the effort?

Tags: opengl, smalltalk, pharo

Ok so I tried to learn `Opengl ES 2` (and opengl 4) during my eastern vacation because I realised that I dont really need Athens or vector graphics for my GUI, since I will be dealing mostly with 3d graphics anyway. (My project "Ephestos" will be an effort of creating a 3d app for pharo, see also "blender")

So when I tried to run the demos I get an error with

```
NBMacGLContextDriver>>supportsCurrentPlatform
    "obviously, for Mac intel-32 only :)"
    ^ NativeBoost platformId = NativeBoostConstants mac32PlaformId
```

My mac is "obviously" not 32-bit but 64 bit, but I dont know if that matters since pharo is only 32 bit anyway. The bug is also obvious, it should be `mac32PlatformId` and not `mac32PlaformId`.

I correct and proceed and gives me a new error this time in

```
NBMacGlApi>>glApiCall: fnSpec index: fnIndex attributes: attributes context: contextToRetry

    ^[
        (NBCallFailureHandler for: contextToRetry) retryWith: [ :targetClass :targetMethod |
            (NBFFICallout
                targetClass: targetClass targetMethod: targetMethod fnSpec: fnSpec)
                stdcall;
                generate: [ :gen | self emitCall: fnIndex generator: gen ]
        ]
    ] on: NBNativeCodeError do: [:err :handler |
        err errorCode = ErrorFnNotAvailable ifTrue: [
            "Native code is installed, but function pointer not loaded yet.
            Try to load function and retry the call"  
            (self tryGetFunctionPointer: (self class glFunctions at: fnIndex)) ifFalse: [ ^ err pass ].
            ^ handler retrySend
            ].
        err pass      
    ]
```

The problem here is that `NBCallFailureHandler` is nowhere to be found. At first I thought my
NB was lagging behind in version so I download the latest Configuration from smalltalk Hub and did

> ConfigurationOfNativeboost loadStable.

it updated without errors but still that class is nowhere to be found.

So my question is this, does it really worth it to struggle with `NBOpengl` or
will it better to learn how `Nativeboost` works and use `Opengl` myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes. NBOpenGL is a pre-made wrapper to OpenGL using NativeBoost, so it saves you time by providing something that you will need to do manually otherwise.
Better to spend some time fixing a configuration than spend a lot of time re-doing the binding.

Comment: thanks, I think I will do just that, try to fix at least the parts that I need for my application. I just wanted the opinion of more experienced smalltalkers that have used and understand the library and its problems.

Comment: yeah... also the configuration should work out of the box. If it is not working, please report in mailing list so maintainers can fix it :)